# reading and plotting an esri shape file in R

Tags: r, vector, geospatial, plot, esri

I'm having difficulties reading in a .shp (esri shape file) into R. I have tried several options in R, and tried to convert the shape file in ArcMap to something that correctly reads in the shape file but nothing worked yet. (In ArcMap I corrected the geometry, converted from single to multipolygon, etc which was probably not necessary or relevant)

It probably has something to with the fact that my shape file contains 'regions' (multi-polygons) instead of 'polygons'...

How can I read that type of shape file correctly in R for plotting? (it looks like a normal shape in ArcMap)

In ArcMap the shape file looks like this:
http://bfast.r-forge.r-project.org/arcmapshape.jpg

(shows a shape file with polygons within other polygons)

In R it looks like this:
[image]

(shows a shape file where some polygons are wrongly filled)

I used the following code in R:

```
require(maptools)
require(rgdal)

newproj <- "+proj=utm +zone=55 +south +ellps=GRS80 +units=m"
shape<- readShapeSpatial(pdir, proj4string = CRS(newproj),repair=TRUE,force_ring=T,verbose=TRUE) # without any errors
plot(shape, col="gray",border="blue", axes=TRUE)

# via rgdal
folder <- c("spatial")
lyr <- c("clipped_forest_mga")
shp <- readOGR(dsn=folder,layer=lyr)
plot(shp, col="gray",border="blue", axes=TRUE)
```

Both plot() commands give the same R result. No errors occur. only the following message

```
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: "P:/Victoria_DSE/BFAST_spatial/vector/PLM_excl_fire03_09_GDA94LL/mgaz94z55/clipped_EG", layer: "clipped_forest_mga"
with 1 features and 4 fields
Feature type: wkbMultiPolygon with 2 dimensions
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: This is a moderately specialised question, and there is a special list for this -- did you consider asking on r-ssig-spatial ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Jan,

Your shapefile has probably been read correctly. It is more likely that the plotting wasn't correct. Try spplot() instead of plot() :

```
spplot(shp, col.regions="gray", col="blue")
```

If your shapefile has more than one column (which is likely), add zcol= 1 (or any other column) so you get only one panel

```
spplot(shp, zcol=1, col.regions="gray", col="blue")
```

If you really want to use plot you have to set a color for the background, because otherwise it will print the holes transparent. So set pbg="white". Try:

```
plot(shp, col="gray", border="blue", axes=TRUE, pbg="white")
```

By the way, the list I think Dirk was referring to is [R-sig-Geo](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/) and you can find there many answers and ask many sig-related questions.

Comment: Very clear answer! Both solutions work. Thanks for your help.

I found some very handy webpages with other R examples to plot spatial maps containing grid and vector data:

http://geography.uoregon.edu/GeogR/examples/maps_examples02.htm
http://r-spatial.sourceforge.net/gallery/

Cheers,
Jan